# How to read parquet files from aws s3 bucket and save them as jsons in jupyter

Tags: amazon-s3, multi-factor-authentication

I am working with in a jupyter notebook with python. I am trying to read all the parquet files within a folder in an aws s3 bucket, and save them as jsons in a folder in my jupyter directory. I have the following code, but I believe it is just reading them, and I would like to save them as jsons. Thank you!

```
bucketname = 'my-bucket'
bucket = response.Bucket(bucketname)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to download the file to your file system instead of loading in memory. Here is an example code snippet that does the job.

```
bucketname = 'my-bucket'
bucket = response.Bucket(bucketname)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    obj.Object().download_file('<specify-the-local-filename>')
```

You can find the docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_file).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to download it as a json file rather than a parquet like it is now?

Comment: That gave me ''s3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute 'download_file'', do you know why this could be?

Comment: @supercool Sorry about that, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `parquet` pip module, will do just that: https://pypi.org/project/parquet/. They have an example as well, copied here for quick ref:

```
import parquet
import json

## assuming parquet file with two rows and three columns:
## foo bar baz
## 1   2   3
## 4   5   6

with open("test.parquet") as fo:
   # prints:
   # {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
   # {"foo": 4, "bar": 5}
   for row in parquet.DictReader(fo, columns=['foo', 'bar']):
       print(json.dumps(row))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to save these jsons, and for it to be done to every file?